# How to delay command execution

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, shell

How to make a program wait till a shell command finishes? For example:

```
Shell("format")
Console.WriteLine("Finished")
```

In this example the line "Finished" is first written and only after then the shell function starts. How to start the shell function first, and only when it has been finished write the line "Finished"?

Comment: @dtb the same as in the example

Comment: Pick a language.  Is it C# or VB.Net?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Shell` can take a parameter specifying whether to wait for the program to complete or not:

```
Shell("format", Wait:=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use processes and `cmd.exe`

```
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
psi.Arguments = @"/C cd C:\windows\system32 && dir";
var proc = Process.Start(psi);
proc.WaitForExit()

Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
```

The `/C` argument at the beginning of whatever command(s) you want to run, means that the shell will run that one command and then exit when it completes.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("C:\bla.exe").WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx). Then use the [Process.WaitForExit Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) to wait for the process you created to exit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may use [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ccf1tfx0.aspx) class.

Create an instance of the process and attach an event handler when the process exist.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx#Y200

Answer (score 0):

Do a quick internet search for "Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.Shell".

I found this: [MSDN microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell.aspx)

It tells me:

> Parameters
>
> Wait
>
> ```
> Type: System.Boolean
> ```
>
> Optional. Boolean. A value indicating whether the Shell function
>   should wait for completion of the program. If Wait is omitted, Shell uses False.